# DSolve doesn't produce the expected result

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following function:

$$B(t) = \frac{a^n}{a^n + t^n}.$$

By taking derivative from both sides with respect to $t$ and after some manipulation, one obtains:

$$B' = - \frac{n}{a} B^2 \left(\frac{1 - B}{B}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}.$$

Now, I want to solve the above differential equation with DSolve, and reproduce my starting function, thus:

```
DSolve[B'[t] == -n ( B[t]^2/a) ((1 - B[t])/B[t])^((n - 1)/n), B[t], t]
```

Mathematica returns another solution. How can I force it to reproduce the above function?

Comment: **By taking derivative from both sides with respect to t
 and after some manipulation, one obtains:** I can't verify this using Mathematica.

Comment: Using Mathematica, it says the ode is $$B'(t)=\frac{n a^n t^{n-1}}{\left(a^n+t^n\right)^2}$$  or `B'[t] == (a^n n t^(-1 + n))/(a^n + t^n)^2;`

Comment: sometimes simplification with side relation works, but not on this one.

Comment: There is no error. It just gives warning **Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found** that is all.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da50P.png)

Comment: AGain, your ode is wrong. It is not based on $B'(t)$ as given initially. Here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSffE.png)  You can use Mathematica to do the derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you started with $B(t)$ and trying to compare the solution of the ode to this $B(t)$. But the $B(t)$ you started with is one solution curve while the solution that `DSolve` returns has an arbitrary constant of integration. So you can *not* just compare the two like this.

You need to find specific value of $c$ to make it match. i.e. the solution returned is whole family of solutions, while your original $B$ is just one member.

The problem is that the $c$ returned is hard to isolate. But forcing $c$ to be a value to the make the ode solution gives the original $B$ works.

```
ClearAll[B, t, n, a];
rhs = a^n/(a^n + t^n);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ode = B'[t] == -n (B[t]^2/a) ((1 - B[t])/B[t])^((n - 1)/n)
sol = DSolveValue[ode, B[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now find the $c$ to make them match

```
cValue=First@Solve[sol==rhs,C[1]];
sol=FullSimplify[sol/.cValue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above $c$ picks the correct member of the family of solutions. But Reduce and `FullSimplify` could not show this. May be there is a workaround. I did not try too hard.

But there is a plot showing they match.

```
Row[{Plot[Evaluate[sol /. {n -> 2, a -> 2}], {t, -1, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "solution of ode", ImageSize -> 300],
  Plot[Evaluate[rhs /. {n -> 2, a -> 2}], {t, -1, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "original B", ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row[{Plot[Evaluate[sol /. {n -> 7, a -> 8}], {t, -1, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "solution of ode", ImageSize -> 300],
  Plot[Evaluate[rhs /. {n -> 8, a -> 8}], {t, -1, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "original B", ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Tim because your $a=23,n=26$ are not compatible with the initial condition $B(15)=1$ you gave to `NDSovle`. If you try to plug these values, you see they do not satisfy the B(t). So you are comparing two different things. To get close to what NDSolve gave, try $a=23,n=-200$

Comment: According to Mathematica, it is not. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvLu4.png)  You see, these values do not satisfy the equation of $B$ at time $t=15$ It says False. Which means the equality is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

The complex power function can be finicky. If we may assume positive values, then we can get the following:

```
DSolve[{
      B'[t] == -n (B[t]^2/a) ((1 - B[t])/B[t])^((n - 1)/n), 
      B[0] == 1}, (* condition for given B[t] *)
 B[t], t] // 
   Simplify[#, a > 0 && t > 0 && n > 1] & //
    PowerExpand // Simplify // Quiet
```

> ```
>  (* {{B[t] -> a^n/(a^n + t^n)}} *)
> ```